# Remove white space at bottom of page xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have this Xamain.Forms app where I hide page title when the device orientation changes. It all works fine but on Android a white space is showing above the content when I switch to horizontal view. You can see how it looks in the pictures below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3jJ0.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tj6vN.png)

This is my xaml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="Kanal10Live.VideoTest">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout x:Name="VideoStack">
        <WebView x:Name="Browser" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"></WebView> 
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

And this is code behind:

```
private double width = 0;
    private double height = 0;
    protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
    {
        base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);

        switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
        {
            case Device.Android:
                if (width != this.width || height != this.height)
                {
                    this.width = width;
                    this.height = height;
                    if (width > height)
                    {
                        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
                        VideoStack.Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal;                            
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, true);
                        VideoStack.Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical;
                    }
                }

                break;

        }

    }
```

The funny thing is that if I use the below code when the page initializes all is fine.

If someone can help me I would be grateful!

Peter

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<Grid>
    <WebView x:Name="Browser" />
</Grid>
```

Grid by default fills the full page. If you don't set any horizontal or vertical options on the web view it should fill the whole grid.

Comment: Unfortunately the same scenario occurs when I add a grid instead of a StackLayout.

Comment: Strange. I'll try and create a test app and see if I can figure out why.